# Perfect sets are uncountable. Proof via $G_\delta$-sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation

To prove the statement, we need the two theorems:

> T1. Let $X$ be a complete metric space and $A\subset X$. Then $A$, with the metric of $X$, is a complete metric space if and only if $A$ is closed in $X$.

> T2. If $X$ is a (nonvoid) complete metric space having no isolated points and $E$ is a countable dense subset of $X$, then $E$ is not a $G_\delta$ set.

The statement:

> If A is a perfect nonvoid subset of a complete metric space, then $A$ is uncountable. [Hint: Use T1 and T2].

I think I'm stuck because I cannot see the usefulness of $G_\delta$ sets.

If $A$ is perfect, then it is equal to its limit points (has no isolated points) and thus $A$ is closed. By T1, $A$ is complete. In particular, if $A$ is a (dense) countable subset, then by T2 $A$ is not a $G_\delta$ set.

This means that $A$ cannot be expressed as the countable intersection of open subsets, fine, but this should rise a contradiction that I cannot see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is closed and therefore complete by the first theorem. Now work in the space $A$. If $A$ were countable, it would be a countable, dense, open subset of itself.

Comment: If I understand, it doesn't matter if $A\subset X$. If $A$ is a complete metric space, then it is both open and closed?

Comment: @user2820579: It’s closed in $X$, which is why it’s complete in the metric that it inherits from $X$. Now we can ignore $X$ and work strictly in the complete metric space $A$, which, like any space, is open in itself. It need not be open in $X$, of course.

Comment: What you say is that, if $A$ is open, countable dense subset of $A$, the $A$ must be a $G_\delta$ set, but by T2 this cannot be, so $A$ is uncountable?

Comment: @user2820579: Exactly: every open set in a space is automatically a $G_\delta$ set in that space, so in particular every space is a dense $G_\delta$ set in itself.